# chartjs v4 legend text not updating when using afterLayout

Tags: chart.js

I am using chartjs v4.  I am modifying the legend text.  I see code gets executed but the legend text does not change.  Here is the code:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    plugins: [{
        afterLayout: chart => {
            chart.legend.legendItems.forEach(
                (label) => {
                    label.text += ' Test';
                    return label;
                }
            )
        }
    }],
```

...

The legend labels remain the same (It does not add "Test" at the end of each label).  What am I missing?  Something is not being refreshed somehow.

**UPDATE/SOLUTION**

First I used afterDraw and that worked.  But Kikon's solution was even better. I noticed that afterDraw was executing twice and therefore updating the legend labels twice unnecessarily. I am going to use Kikon's solution and use afterUpdate instead of afterDraw:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        plugins: [{
            afterUpdate: (chart, args, opts) => {
                chart.legend.legendItems.forEach(
                    (label) => {
                        label.text += ' Test ';
                        return label;
                    }
                )
            }
        }],
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The labels are re-built in the legend plugin's `afterUpdate`
([source code](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/v4.4.2/src/plugins/plugin.legend.js#L625)),
which is called [later](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#chart-update)
than `afterLayout`; so, there are two possibilities:

- set your plugin code to change the labels in `afterUpdate` rather than in `afterLayout`
- [probably unnecessarily hacky] remove the legend plugin's `afterUpdate` to avoid the redundant legend items recompute:

  ```js
  Chart.registry.getPlugin('legend').afterUpdate = () => null;
  ```

As discussed with Robert Smith in comments, `afterUpdate` (from the
first solution above) is the earliest called plugin hook that can be used to
change the label texts. Any of the [render](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#rendering)
process hooks (from `beforeRender` to `afterRender`) could also be used.

I'd add here, for reference, that there is another method to adjust the
legend labels dynamically, which is to customize the
[`generateLabels`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration)
function of the `options.plugins.legend.labels` namespace. The difficulty with
it is that it should return several options for the legend item (see [Legend Item Interface](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-item-interface))
that one is not concerned with here. To avoid that, one might call the
default `generateLabels` function first:

```js
const config = {
    //..... data, other configuration items
    options: {
        // .... other options
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    generateLabels(chart){
                        // default labels
                        const labels = chart.registry.getPlugin("legend")
                            .defaults.labels.generateLabels(chart);
                        
                        labels.forEach(
                            label => {
                                if(!label.text.match(/ Test$/)){ 
                                // avoid applying the change multiple times
                                    label.text += ' Test';
                                }
                            }
                        );
                        return labels;
                    }
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you Kikon we posted two different answers at the same time!  I used afterDraw on my answer.  Should I use afterUpdate instead of afterDraw as you suggested instead?

Comment: @RobertSmith well, `afterUpdate` is the earliest stage where it can be done; any hook of the render cycle also works, even `beforeRender` or `beforeDraw`.

Comment: Thank you I did notice it executes afterDraw twice (modifies legend label twice) and afterUpdate only executes once (modifieds the legend labels only once) so I am going to use your suggestion: afterUpdate instead of using afterDraw.

Comment: @RobertSmith Yes, and that reminds me that any of these handlers might be called multiple times, so it's better to check that the labels don't already have the text change you want to implement before changing them. I'll also add to the answer a short reference to the scriptable label option, that might be useful to others that read it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found!  The solution is to use **afterDraw** instead of **afterLayout** as follows:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            plugins: [{
                afterDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
                    chart.legend.legendItems.forEach(
                        (label) => {
                            label.text += ' Test ';
                            return label;
                        }
                    )
                }
            }],
...
```

Now the legend text successfully updates!

**UPDATE**

Kikon's solution was even better.  I noticed that afterDraw was executing twice and therefore updating the legend labels twice unnecessarily.  I am going to use Kikon's solution and use afterUpdate instead of afterDraw:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            plugins: [{
                afterUpdate: (chart, args, opts) => {
                    chart.legend.legendItems.forEach(
                        (label) => {
                            label.text += ' Test ';
                            return label;
                        }
                    )
                }
            }],
...
```